# output caching on static pages?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Does output caching help boost the performance of asp.net mvc pages that just consist of html, css, images, and javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about pure static resources such as images, javascript, css, ... they are served by IIS and cached. If you are talking about a *static* ASPX page then output caching will definitely boost performance.

Comment: I'm referring to asp.net mvc pages that are like regular html pages (no server-side coding)